# changing permission of all files in folder

Tags: batch-file, permissions

This is a bat file for locking my picture folder and it was very good until I changed my windows and it changed all file permission to some code user(some number).

The .bat code is here

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder Locker
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER

:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure u want to Lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM

:LOCK
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End

:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%==Password goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End

:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end

:MDLOCKER
md Locker
echo Locker created successfully
goto End

:End
```

I need some `.bat` code to change permissions of all files in the folder.

I changed the main folder permission but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `icacls`

To lock and deny all permissions, type

```
icacls FileName /deny %USERNAME%:(F)
```

To unlock and allow all permissions, type

```
icacls FileName /grant %USERNAME%:(F)
```